# The type or namespace name 'WizardFramework' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wizard

When I build a Add-in, wizard project, I got this error message:

> Error  7   The type or namespace name 'WizardFramework' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   D:\soamol\soam\SDK\IDEIntegrations\VisualStudio\SymVSIntegration\SymCsOnboardingWizard\Wizard\OnboardingPage4_AppDetails.cs 3   17  SymCsOnboardingWizard

VS2008 .Net3.5 sp1

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlWizardFramework.dll` assembly as a reference to your project?

You will also need to add a `using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlWizardFramework;` statement to the top of the code file you want to use this class in.

Comment: en. hi I have add this : using Microsoft.WizardFramework; When compile, I got the error.

Comment: @dma - Have you added both a project reference _and_ the using statement?

Comment: yeah, I can't find Microsoft.WizardFramework in the reference list. Do I lost any patch?

Comment: hi. I find this dll: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Help 8\Microsoft.WizardFramework.dll, and add it to the project manually. It works. Thank you for you help @Oded.